# Why is there Textual Blur on Wikipedia When I Browse it?

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card

I browse with Google Chrome and when I scroll on Wikipedia, the I see blurred text. Randomly scrolling up and down may fix it, but I'm curious what causes it in the first place.

**It does not happen with any other site**. That has me really curious.

Could it be a hardware issue? Why does it happen only with Wikipedia?

[image: Blurred Wikipedia's site image.]

Edit:

**System Info**

- Model: HP EliteBook 8470p
- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Graphics card: Intel HD Graphics 4000
- Browser: Chrome v109

Switching to in-Cognito makes no difference - it still happens.

Comment: Does this happen when Chrome is in Incognito mode (to disable all extensions) ?

Comment: Please edit your question: What OS are you on? I assume Windows, you please confirm. What is the make and model of the PC you are using? And if you have a desktop with a custom GPU, what is the GPU make and model?

Comment: Check whether an updated version of the graphics driver is available, it could fix this problem.

Comment: @harrymc It does. I have edited the question to reveal it.

Comment: @DanielB I suppose I could do that. Albeit I was hoping to get some technical explanation of it. I am really curious why it happens at all, moreso the fact that I only seem to experience it on a single site (Wikipedia). Perhaps it's a question for StackOverflow.